# Activating a select's event onfocus on server side

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have this select, then on focus it suppose to activate a function in the code  behind, but it doesn't.
what is the problem?

html:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
            <select id="Day" name="Day" class="regis" style="width:109px" onfocus="Day_Click" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
               <option value="" selected="selected">Day</option>
             </select>
       </td>
       <td class="un" id="dateE" runat="server">
       </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i have this function in the code behind:

```
public void Day_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (true)
    {
        this.dateE.InnerText = "Enter a Month and a Year First";
        this.dateE.Attributes.Add("class", "feedback");
    }
    else
    {
        this.dateE.InnerText = "";
        this.dateE.Attributes.Add("class", "un");
    }
}
```

the class `un` and `feedback` works, i have them working on other elements.

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

is because you must call the function in the event

```
<select id="Day" name="Day" class="regis" style="width:109px" onfocus="Day_Click();" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
```

and this will call a function on the client side and not the server, so this makes an ajax call

Comment: i dont understanf what u have changed?